# MySQL 5.5 Database Query Help

Tags: sql, mysql

I am having a few issues with a DB query.

I have two tables, students (Fields: FirstName, LastName, StdSSN), and teachers (TFirstName, TLastName, TSSN) which I've stripped down for this example. I need to perform a query that will return all the students except for the students that are teachers themselves.

I have the query

```
SELECT student.FirstName, student.LastName
FROM `student`,`teachers`
WHERE student.StdSSN=teachers.TSSN
```

Which gives me a list of all the teachers who are also students it does not provide me with a list of students who are not teachers, so I tried changing to:

```
SELECT student.FirstName, student.LastName
FROM `student`,`teachers`
WHERE student.StdSSN!=teachers.TSSN
```

Which gives me a list of all the students with many duplicate values so I am a little stuck here. How can I change things to return a list of all students who are not teachers? I was thinking INNER/OUTER/SELF-JOIN and was playing with that for a few hours but things became complicated and I did not accomplish anything so I've pretty much given up.

Can anyone give me any advice? I did see the query before and it was pretty simple, but I've failed somewhere.

Comment: It's partly, it's for a college DB class, the full query is much more complex and I have it solved I just could not figure out how to exclude students being teachers as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Using NOT IN

```
SELECT s.*
  FROM STUDENTS s
 WHERE s.stdssn NOT IN (SELECT t.tssn
                          FROM TEACHERS t)
```

### Using NOT EXISTS

```
SELECT s.*
  FROM STUDENTS s
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                     FROM TEACHERS t
                    WHERE t.tssn = s.stdssn)
```

### Using LEFT JOIN / IS NULL

```
   SELECT s.*
     FROM STUDENTS s
LEFT JOIN TEACHERS t ON t.tssn = s.stdssn
    WHERE t.column IS NULL
```

I used "column" for any column in TEACHERS other than what is joined on.

### Comparison:

[If the column(s) compared are nullable (value can be NULL), NOT EXISTS is the best choice](http://explainextended.com/2010/05/27/left-join-is-null-vs-not-in-vs-not-exists-nullable-columns/).  Otherwise, LEFT JOIN/IS NULL is the best choice (for MySQL).

Comment: @Eric Petroelje: `MINUS` is Oracle specific, vs the ANSI `EXCEPT` (and `EXCEPT ALL`).  To my knowledge, MySQL doesn't support either.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, I spent about 3 hours on this. I'm going to read up on joins later this evening.

Comment: @user591162: Good join primer: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html